# Can not find Documentation for salesforce lightning standard events

Tags: lightning

I need to refer to documentation for various standard events available for salesforce lightning like  $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
I searched alot from my end but no success
Even if links are given by any dev user in forums the link is found broken

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reliable source you can use is the AuraDocs documentation, which is found in your org at: `https://<my-domain>.my.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app` (alternatively, you can use `https://login.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app` for production and `https://test.salesforce.com/auradocs/reference.app` for sandboxes). It will show you all standard and custom events, components, interfaces, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Another pretty useful place is component library generally available since Summer 18: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/

Pretty great about this resource is that there are a lot of examples (also visually represented) that you can use in your daily development.

Event part is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/events

Comment: Can't mark two items as correct answer but thanks :). Thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the events related docs in this URL

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_events.htm

Comment: This is for custom event. I am asking about standard salesforce lightning standard events like e.force:edit event, by which we can edit a record just by specifying record Id

Comment: Thats the home page..please scroll down and see the left tree to find the list

Comment: yea correct. checked now